# Can in-app functionality be bought outside of Google Play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I've come across a collection of android apps that utilise a questionable practice.
With the help of misleading ads user gets tricked into buying an app via SMS service (with prices up to 10 EUR). Afterwards the user then can enter an activation code in the free app distributed on Google Play store.

The entire operation is in grey-area, because it is the user itself who sends the SMS and is responsible for the cost. Due to the nature of the ads, its mostly unsuspecting older people that get tricked into this, because they assume that they must do it or they'll have problems with their device.

In app functionality being sold outside of the app store would most likely be a violation of Apple Store and the app could be reported.

I am wondering if there's similar rules for Play Store, so that this practice could be reported to Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that Google allows this practice for now, but they are already working on changing it. From my experience, Google allows devs to use any payment/licensing model that their app requires. However, this is subject to change and the end results will be something similar with Apple's policy.

From their [support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10281818?hl=en#zippy=) page, it seems that from January 2021, they require that all new apps will use the GooglePlay IAP API. Existing apps have until the end of September to make the switch. As with any other policy, there are some exceptions, but please check the official page to receive the correct information.